# Scrapy spider returning None but Xpath is correct

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl a site using scrapy and i'm in the early stages of coding my spider. To begin with i'm only trying to return the names of films but when i run the spider the name returns 'None' or [ ] for each entry.

I've checked the Xpath using the 'XPath Helper' chrome extension and it appears to be correct on there so i'm not sure why the spider isn't returning the film names. The website i'm trying to crawl is https://www.finder.com/uk/netflix-movies and the code for my spider is:

```
import scrapy

class finderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'finderSpider'    
    start_urls = ['https://www.finder.com/uk/netflix-movies']

    def parse(self,response):
        for film in response.xpath('//tr'):
            yield {
                'name': film.xpath('/td/div/b/text()').extract()
            }
```

I'm fairly new to this so sorry if there's something obvious i'm missing. The website seems to allow bots and all settings and middlewares files are unchanged from the default.

Below is an example of one line of the response in the terminal:

```
2020-04-29 13:31:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.finder.com/uk/netflix-movies>
{'name': []}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be working with this small adjustment:

```
import scrapy

class finderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'finderSpider'    
    start_urls = ['https://www.finder.com/uk/netflix-movies']

    def parse(self,response):
        for film in response.xpath('//tr'):
            yield {
                'name': film.xpath('./td/b/text()').extract()
            }
```

Comment: Brilliant! thank you so much for that, been stuck all morning with it